# how to use google translate in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using same concept as given in this thread
[JavaScript/jQuery - Get text and translate it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388127/javascript-jquery-get-text-and-translate-it). and [jQuery translate + toggle, how to link the two?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308818/jquery-translate-toggle-how-to-link-the-two.I) need to convert text written by user in input field in german language and display on label after click of button.
can you please tell me how I will use google translate ?
fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/vjk2o94f/1/

```
<input type="text" />
<label id="changetext"></label>
<button id="convert">convert</button>
```

Comment: Google Translate API is a paid API...

Comment: possible duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919522/how-can-i-use-google-translate-via-ajax-using-jquery